# How to use an already built html template in django?

Tags: django

I have an already built HTML template for eCommerce to use in Django. But when i implemented it with all the static files are set, the template is not rendered when i run the server, the page is completely blank. However there was no error in the terminal as well as the debug console. When i view the page source, i can see all the HTML elements. I dont know what is the issue here. Please give me a hint, thank you!

[image: the page is blank]

[image: page source]

- **base.html**

  ```
  {% load static %}

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
      <title>Home</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  {% include "base/css.html"%}

  </head>
  <body class="animsition">

  {% block content %}{% endblock %}


  {% include "base/js.html" %}

  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- **home_page.html**

  ```
      {% extends "base.html" %}

      {% load static %}

      {% block content %}

      <!-- my content here -->

      {% endblock %}
  ```
- **views.py**

  ```
  from django.shortcuts import render


  def home_page(request):
      return render(request, 'home_page.html', {})
  ```
- **urls.py**

  ```
  from .views import home_page
  urlpatterns = [
      path('', home_page, name='home'),
  ]
  ```

Comment: Yeah, actually, you are going to render into `home_page.html` but may be the template file name is `home.html`?! I've just ran this entire project like this and have no issue. Check the `settings.py` as well. I think this is just a problem of configurations or similar. In some cases, you may try changing `re_path` to `path` for more safe.

Comment: No, i have edited my post, the template name is `home_page.html`. I alse have checked my `settings.py` file for config issues but in the browser console, all the page's sources including the static files are all there.

Comment: What happens when you browse this file manually in the browser?

Comment: It shows the HTML contents without css and js. It also includes `{% extends "base.html" %} {% load static %} {% block content %}` at the top and `{% endblock %}` at the bottom.

Comment: @HuyNguyen: There are so many cases can happen here. Sometimes CSS or JS will hide the content. You may try removing JS/CSS and start with clean pages. I guess you are using https://git.blivesta.com/animsition/ to get the changing pages transition.

Comment: @anhtran: Thanks for your suggestion! You were right, the problem caused by the `.scss` files and after some researches on google, i have finally fixed this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused due to the `.scss` files which included in the already built HTML template that i used. They requires some appropriate Django packages in order to run.

Here are some solutions for using SASS/SCSS files in Django:

https://www.terencelucasyap.com/using-sass-django/

https://www.accordbox.com/blog/how-use-scss-sass-your-django-project-python-way/